# Права доступа к файлам в linux

Tags: linux

Задача: запустить 2 сайта от разных юзеров на одном серваке таким образом, чтобы каждый юзер не имел доступа к файлам другого юзера.
Создал юзеров. Создал папки для сайтов в директории www апача, установил на один из сайтов wordpress и возникла проблемка.

У второго юзера нет доступа к папке первого,

> /var/www/first/

но если попробовать

> cat /var/www/first/index.php

То баш спокойно выводит содержимое файла на экран.
А если менять права на самих файлах сайта, то возникает ошибка 500.

Можно ли, не трогая апач и файлы его сайтов, запретить доступ к файлам в папке другому юзеру?

Comment: Вы что-то не то наконфигурировали. Вам нужно смотреть в сторону VirtualDomain (или как оно там называется), там же в конфиге сервера можно расставить ACL.

Comment: **баш спокойно выводит содержимое файла на экран** - Вы от какого пользователя эту команду вводили ? Сдаётся мне - от root-a. Полностью согласен с предыдущим комментарием - не надо рукамит НИЧЕГО создавать. Правильно настройте раздел виртуальных серверов и будет всё ОК.

Comment: @Sergey я конечно идиот, но не настолько, чтоб проверять права доступа от рута

Comment: а как вы предоставили пользователям права? 
Попробуйте сделать владельцами каталогов пользователей к примеру так chown -R user1.www-data /var/www/first/ и chown -R user2.www-data /var/www/second при условии что user1 и user2 не входят в группу www-data (если апач запущен от www-data)